# How to use the ARCore camera image in OpenCV in an Unity Android app?

Tags: c#, android, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use OpenCV for hand gesture recognition in my Unity ARCore game. However, with the deprecation of TextureReaderAPI, the only way to capture the image from the camera is by using `Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes()`. The problem with that is not only that the image is in 640x480 resolution (this cannot be changed AFAIK), but it is also in YUV_420_888 format.
As if that were not enough, OpenCV does not have free C#/Unity packages, so if I do not want to cash out 20$ for a paid package, I need to use available C++ or python versions. How do I move the YUV image to OpenCV, convert it to an RGB (or HSV) color space, and then either do some processing on it or return it back to Unity?

Comment: There is a free OpenCV package avaiable on the Unity asset store: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-plus-unity-85928

Answer (score 2):

In this example, I will use C++ OpenCV libraries and Visual Studio 2017 and I will try to capture ARCore camera image, move it to OpenCV (as efficiently as possible), convert it to RGB color space, then move it back to Unity C# code and save it in the phone's memory.

Firstly, we have to create a C++ dynamic library project to use with OpenCV. For this, I highly recommend to follow **both** Pierre Baret's and Ninjaman494's answers on this question: [OpenCV + Android + Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399921/opencv-android-unity). The process is rather straightforward, and if you will not deviate from their answers too much (i.e. you can safely download a newer than 3.3.1 version of OpenCV, but be careful when compiling for ARM64 instead of ARM, etc.), you should be able to call a C++ function from C#.

In my experience, I had to solve two problems - firstly, if you made the project part of your C# solution instead of creating a new solution, Visual Studio will keep messing with your configuration, like trying to compile a x86 version instead of an ARM version. To save yourself the hassle, create a completely separate solution. The other problem is that some functions failed to link for me, thus throwing a undefined reference linker error (`undefined reference to 'cv::error(int, std::string const&, char const*, char const*, int`, to be exact). If this happens and the problem is with a function that you do not really need, just recreate the function in your code - for instance if you have problems with `cv::error`, add this code in the end of your .cpp file:

```cpp
namespace cv {
    __noreturn void error(int a, const String & b, const char * c, const char * d, int e) {
        throw std::string(b);
    }
}
```

Sure, this is ugly and dirty way to do things, so if you know how to fix the linker error, please do so and let me know.

Now, you should have a working C++ code that compiles and can be run from a Unity Android application. However, what we want is for OpenCV to not return a number, but to convert an image. So change your code to this:

**.h file**

```
extern "C" {
    namespace YOUR_OWN_NAMESPACE
    {
        int ConvertYUV2RGBA(unsigned char *, unsigned char *, int, int);
    }
}
```

**.cpp file**

```
extern "C" {
    int YOUR_OWN_NAMESPACE::ConvertYUV2RGBA(unsigned char * inputPtr, unsigned char * outputPtr, int width, int height) {

        // Create Mat objects for the YUV and RGB images. For YUV, we need a 
        // height*1.5 x width image, that has one 8-bit channel. We can also tell
        // OpenCV to have this Mat object "encapsulate" an existing array, 
        // which is inputPtr.
        // For RGB image, we need a height x width image, that has three 8-bit
        // channels. Again, we tell OpenCV to encapsulate the outputPtr array.
        // Thanks to specifying existing arrays as data sources, no copying
        // or memory allocation has to be done, and the process is highly
        // effective.
        cv::Mat input_image(height + height / 2, width, CV_8UC1, inputPtr);
        cv::Mat output_image(height, width, CV_8UC3, outputPtr);

        // If any of the images has not loaded, return 1 to signal an error.
        if (input_image.empty() || output_image.empty()) {
            return 1;
        }

        // Convert the image. Now you might have seen people telling you to use 
        // NV21 or 420sp instead of NV12, and BGR instead of RGB. I do not
        // understand why, but this was the correct conversion for me. 
        // If you have any problems with the color in the output image,
        // they are probably caused by incorrect conversion. In that case,
        // I can only recommend you the trial and error method.
        cv::cvtColor(input_image, output_image, cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV12);

        // Now that the result is safely saved in outputPtr, we can return 0.
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now, rebuild the solution (`Ctrl + Shift + B`) and copy the `libProjectName.so` file to Unity's `Plugins/Android` folder, as in the linked answer.

The next thing is to save the image from ARCore, move it to C++ code, and get it back. Let us add this **inside the class** in our C# script:

```
[DllImport("YOUR_OWN_NAMESPACE")]
    public static extern int ConvertYUV2RGBA(IntPtr input, IntPtr output, int width, int height);
```

You will be prompted by Visual Studio to add `System.Runtime.InteropServices` using clause - do so.
This allows us to use the C++ function in our C# code. Now, let's add this function to our C# component:

```
public Texture2D CameraToTexture()
    {
        // Create the object for the result - this has to be done before the 
        // using {} clause.
        Texture2D result;

        // Use using to make sure that C# disposes of the CameraImageBytes afterwards
        using (CameraImageBytes camBytes = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes())
        {

            // If acquiring failed, return null
            if (!camBytes.IsAvailable)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("camBytes not available");
                return null;
            }

            // To save a YUV_420_888 image, you need 1.5*pixelCount bytes.
            // I will explain later, why.

            byte[] YUVimage = new byte[(int)(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height * 1.5f)];

            // As CameraImageBytes keep the Y, U and V data in three separate
            // arrays, we need to put them in a single array. This is done using
            // native pointers, which are considered unsafe in C#.
            unsafe
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height; i++)
                {
                    YUVimage[i] = *((byte*)camBytes.Y.ToPointer() + (i * sizeof(byte)));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height / 4; i++)
                {
                    YUVimage[(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height) + 2 * i] = *((byte*)camBytes.U.ToPointer() + (i * camBytes.UVPixelStride * sizeof(byte)));
                    YUVimage[(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height) + 2 * i + 1] = *((byte*)camBytes.V.ToPointer() + (i * camBytes.UVPixelStride * sizeof(byte)));
                }
            }

            // Create the output byte array. RGB is three channels, therefore
            // we need 3 times the pixel count
            byte[] RGBimage = new byte[camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height * 3];

            // GCHandles help us "pin" the arrays in the memory, so that we can
            // pass them to the C++ code.
            GCHandle YUVhandle = GCHandle.Alloc(YUVimage, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            GCHandle RGBhandle = GCHandle.Alloc(RGBimage, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            // Call the C++ function that we created.
            int k = ConvertYUV2RGBA(YUVhandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), RGBhandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), camBytes.Width, camBytes.Height);

            // If OpenCV conversion failed, return null
            if (k != 0)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Color conversion - k != 0");
                return null;
            }

            // Create a new texture object
            result = new Texture2D(camBytes.Width, camBytes.Height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

            // Load the RGB array to the texture, send it to GPU
            result.LoadRawTextureData(RGBimage);
            result.Apply();

            // Save the texture as an PNG file. End the using {} clause to
            // dispose of the CameraImageBytes.
            File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/tex.png", result.EncodeToPNG());
        }

        // Return the texture.
        return result;
    }
```

To be able to run `unsafe` code, you also need to allow it in Unity. Go to Player Settings (`Edit > Project Settings > Player Settings` and check the `Allow unsafe code` checkbox.)

Now, you can call the CameraToTexture() function, let's say, every 5 seconds from Update(), and the camera image should be saved as `/Android/data/YOUR_APPLICATION_PACKAGE/files/tex.png`. The image will probably be landscape oriented, even if you held the phone in portrait mode, but this is not that hard to fix anymore. Also, you might notice a freeze everytime the image is saved - I recommend calling this function in a separate thread because of this. Also, the most demanding operation here is saving the image as an PNG file, so if you need it for any other reason, you should be fine (still use the separate thread, though).

If you want to undestand the YUV_420_888 format, why you need a 1.5*pixelCount array, and why we modified the arrays the way we did, read https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV/#NV12. Other websites seem to have incorrect information about how this format works.

Also, feel free to comment me with any issues you might have, and I will try to help with them, as well as any feedback for both the code and answer.

APPENDIX 1: According to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html, you should use GetRawTextureData instead of LoadRawTextureData, to prevent copying. To do this, just pin the array returned by GetRawTextureData instead of the RGBimage array (which you can remove). Also, do not forget to call result.Apply(); afterwards.

APPENDIX 2: Do not forget to call Free() on both GCHandles when you are done using them.

Comment: Did you just ask a question and answer it pretending you are someone else?

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/.

Also I am not pretending to be someone else. I just write as 'us', which means 'us' programmers that need to use OpenCV in our ARCore projects. 'You' references the person reading this - this is not something that I have done in the time this text is written.

Comment: Did not know that. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get the full resolution CPU image in Arcore 1.8.

I can now get the full camera resolution with cameraimagebytes.

put this in your class variables:

```
private ARCoreSession.OnChooseCameraConfigurationDelegate m_OnChoseCameraConfiguration = null;
```

put this in Start()

```
m_OnChoseCameraConfiguration = _ChooseCameraConfiguration; ARSessionManager.RegisterChooseCameraConfigurationCallback(m_OnChoseCameraConfiguration); ARSessionManager.enabled = false; ARSessionManager.enabled = true;
```

Add this callback to the class:

```
private int _ChooseCameraConfiguration(List<CameraConfig> supportedConfigurations) { return supportedConfigurations.Count - 1; }
```

Once you add those, you should have cameraimagebytes returning the full resolution of the camera.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who want to try this with OpencvForUnity:

```
public Mat getCameraImage()
{
    // Use using to make sure that C# disposes of the CameraImageBytes afterwards
    using (CameraImageBytes camBytes = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes())
    {

        // If acquiring failed, return null
        if (!camBytes.IsAvailable)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("camBytes not available");
            return null;
        }

        // To save a YUV_420_888 image, you need 1.5*pixelCount bytes.
        // I will explain later, why.
        byte[] YUVimage = new byte[(int)(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height * 1.5f)];

        // As CameraImageBytes keep the Y, U and V data in three separate
        // arrays, we need to put them in a single array. This is done using
        // native pointers, which are considered unsafe in C#.
        unsafe
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height; i++)
            {
                YUVimage[i] = *((byte*)camBytes.Y.ToPointer() + (i * sizeof(byte)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height / 4; i++)
            {
                YUVimage[(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height) + 2 * i] = *((byte*)camBytes.U.ToPointer() + (i * camBytes.UVPixelStride * sizeof(byte)));
                YUVimage[(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height) + 2 * i + 1] = *((byte*)camBytes.V.ToPointer() + (i * camBytes.UVPixelStride * sizeof(byte)));
            }
        }

        // Create the output byte array. RGB is three channels, therefore
        // we need 3 times the pixel count
        byte[] RGBimage = new byte[camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height * 3];

        // GCHandles help us "pin" the arrays in the memory, so that we can
        // pass them to the C++ code.
        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(YUVimage, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();


        Mat input = new Mat(camBytes.Height + camBytes.Height / 2, camBytes.Width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Mat output = new Mat(camBytes.Height, camBytes.Width, CvType.CV_8UC3);

        Utils.copyToMat(pointer, input);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(input, output, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV12);

        pinnedArray.Free();

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of this which just uses the free plugin OpenCV Plus Unity. Very simple to set up and great documentation if you are familiar with OpenCV.

This implementation rotates the image properly using OpenCV, stores them into memory and upon exiting the app, saves them to file. I have tried to strip all Unity aspects from the code so that the function GetCameraImage() can be run on a separate thread.

I can confirm it works on Andoird (GS7), I presume it will work pretty universally.

```cs
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using GoogleARCore;
        using UnityEngine;
        using OpenCvSharp;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

        public class CamImage : MonoBehaviour
        {

            public static List<Mat> AllData = new List<Mat>();

            public static void GetCameraImage()
            {

                // Use using to make sure that C# disposes of the CameraImageBytes afterwards
                using (CameraImageBytes camBytes = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes())
                {

                    // If acquiring failed, return null
                    if (!camBytes.IsAvailable)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    // To save a YUV_420_888 image, you need 1.5*pixelCount bytes.
                    // I will explain later, why.
                    byte[] YUVimage = new byte[(int)(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height * 1.5f)];

                    // As CameraImageBytes keep the Y, U and V data in three separate
                    // arrays, we need to put them in a single array. This is done using
                    // native pointers, which are considered unsafe in C#.
                    unsafe
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height; i++)
                        {
                            YUVimage[i] = *((byte*)camBytes.Y.ToPointer() + (i * sizeof(byte)));
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height / 4; i++)
                        {
                            YUVimage[(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height) + 2 * i] = *((byte*)camBytes.U.ToPointer() + (i * camBytes.UVPixelStride * sizeof(byte)));
                            YUVimage[(camBytes.Width * camBytes.Height) + 2 * i + 1] = *((byte*)camBytes.V.ToPointer() + (i * camBytes.UVPixelStride * sizeof(byte)));
                        }
                    }

                    // GCHandles help us "pin" the arrays in the memory, so that we can
                    // pass them to the C++ code.
                    GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(YUVimage, GCHandleType.Pinned);

                    IntPtr pointerYUV = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

                    Mat input = new Mat(camBytes.Height + camBytes.Height / 2, camBytes.Width, MatType.CV_8UC1, pointerYUV);
                    Mat output = new Mat(camBytes.Height, camBytes.Width, MatType.CV_8UC3);

                    Cv2.CvtColor(input, output, ColorConversionCodes.YUV2BGR_NV12);// YUV2RGB_NV12);

                    // FLIP AND TRANPOSE TO VERTICAL
                    Cv2.Transpose(output, output);
                    Cv2.Flip(output, output, FlipMode.Y);

                   AllData.Add(output);
                   pinnedArray.Free();
                }

            }
        }
```

I then call ExportImages() when exiting the program to save to file.

```
    private void ExportImages()
    {
        /// Write Camera intrinsics to text file
        var path = Application.persistentDataPath;
        StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(path + @"/intrinsics.txt");
        sr.WriteLine(CameraIntrinsicsOutput.text);
        Debug.Log(CameraIntrinsicsOutput.text);
        sr.Close();
        // Loop through Mat List, Add to Texture and Save.
        for (var i = 0; i < CamImage.AllData.Count; i++)
        {
            Mat imOut = CamImage.AllData[i];
            Texture2D result = Unity.MatToTexture(imOut);
            result.Apply();

            byte[] im = result.EncodeToJPG(100);
            string fileName = "/IMG" + i + ".jpg";
            File.WriteAllBytes(path + fileName, im);
            string messge = "Succesfully Saved Image To " + path + "\n";
            Debug.Log(messge);
            Destroy(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you already fix this.

But for anyone who want to combine AR with hand gesture recognition and tracking, try Manomotion: https://www.manomotion.com/

free SDk and work prefect in 12/2020.

Use the SDK Community Edition and Download ARFoundation version